# ffmpeg: set fixed GIF framerate while using filter_complex

Tags: ffmpeg, video, gif

I'm using ffmpeg to create a GIF from a sequence of images.

Also using filter_complex option to generate a boomerang fx.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 20 -i frames/%07d.png -y -filter_complex [0]reverse[r];[0][r]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,fps=20,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse -r 20 output.gif
```

The framedelay of output.gif is either 40ms (the default 25fps), or alternating delays, like for example:
frame 1,3,5,7.... 20ms
frame 2,4,6,8.... 30ms

I would like to specify a framerate, resulting in the corresponding fixed framedelay.

Like 20fps = 50ms framedelay ‍♂️

Comment: How do you know the framedelay is not 50msec? Using your command, `ffprobe -show_frames output.gif`, shows: `pkt_duration_time=0.050000`. What is your the version of FFmpeg? I think it should also work with out setting FPS 3 times: `ffmpeg -framerate 20 -i frames/%07d.png -y -filter_complex [0]reverse[r];[0][r]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse output.gif`

Comment: sorry, my bad -  picked the wrong example...


when using framerate 30 for example, ffprobe shows alternating delay like

pkt_duration_time=0.040000
pkt_duration_time=0.030000
pkt_duration_time=0.030000
pkt_duration_time=0.040000
pkt_duration_time=0.030000
pkt_duration_time=0.030000

but i now guess that is just ffmpegs way of avoiding decimals?

ffmpeg v5.0.1 btw

Comment: Yes, according to [this post](https://community.aseprite.org/t/animated-gif-export-rounding-frame-durations/1181/3): "Animated gifs can only have frame durations in increments of 1/100 of a second (0.01s, 0.02s etc)". So 0.033333seconds is rounded to 0.03 and to 0.04.